# JavaFX 2.2 Editor Resizing of Shapes

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to build an JavaFX Graphics Editor with object-orientated patterns, such as Prototype, Composite, Singleton, etc. The problem I have, is to resize an already drawn shape in my AnchorPane. So my idea would be to click i.e. on a rectangle, then a sourrounding border appears which small buttons in each corner to start resizing for that rectangle. Imagine Photoshop resizing, there you also hava such a border, you know. So how can I do this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution shown in my Graphics Editor.

https://github.com/djessich/GraphicsEditor